# I need to include images into my gallery that are saved in my database

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I need my gallery to show images that are saved within my database please. So rather than me using the images source tag, I need the gallery to be filled with what's saved in the database please. So essentially showing the user all the images that ONLY belong to them if that makes sense? I guess the html code of the gallery should fall within the php while loop ?

The html gallery code:

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="grid-full">
        <h3>ALL OF MY COMPETITION ENTRIES</h3>                  
            <div class="masonry">               
            <div class="item">
                <a href="Images/Nude.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery" data-title="Nude Pallette"><img alt src="Images/Nude.jpg" class="ImgRound"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="Images/LakeDistrict.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery" data-title="The Lake District UK"><img alt src="Images/LakeDistrict.jpg" class="ImgRound"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="Images/MarbleCase.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery" data-title="Mac Bliss"><img alt src="Images/MarbleCase.jpg" class="ImgRound"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="Images/HeadwoodBeach.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery" data-title="Headwood Beach"><img alt src="Images/HeadwoodBeach.jpg" class="ImgRound"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="Images/MacDesk.png" data-lightbox="gallery" data-title="Mac"><img alt src="Images/MacDesk.png" class="ImgRound"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="Images/CoffeeonTable.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery" data-title="Fresh Latte"><img alt src="Images/CoffeeonTable.jpg" class="ImgRound"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="Images/SilverMarble.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery" data-title="Mood Board"><img alt src="Images/SilverMarble.jpg" class="ImgRound"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="Images/Peonies.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery" data-title="Peonies"><img alt src="Images/Peonies.jpg" class="ImgRound"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="Images/Trousers.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery" data-title="Checked Trousers"><img alt src="Images/Trousers.jpg" class="ImgRound"></a>
            </div>  
            <div class="item">
                <a href="Images/Greys.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery" data-title="Greys Pallette"><img alt src="Images/Greys.jpg" class="ImgRound"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="Images/Sunset.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery" data-title="Places I would rather be..."><img alt src="Images/Sunset.jpg" class="ImgRound"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="Images/Grey2.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery" data-title="Simple Sweater"><img alt src="Images/Grey2.jpg" class="ImgRound"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="Images/Nature.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery" data-title="Sunrise"><img alt src="Images/Nature.jpg" class="ImgRound"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="Images/autumn.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery" data-title="Autumn"><img alt src="Images/autumn.jpg" class="ImgRound"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="Images/Tulips.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery" data-title="White Tulips"><img alt src="Images/Tulips.jpg" class="ImgRound"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="Images/Pink.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery" data-title="Mood Board"><img alt src="Images/Pink.jpg" class="ImgRound"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="Images/Outfit.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery" data-title="Outfit Ideas"><img alt src="Images/Outfit.jpg" class="ImgRound"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="Images/BandW.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery" data-title="Simple"><img alt src="Images/BandW.jpg" class="ImgRound"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="Images/TheLakeDistrict.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery" data-title="The Lake District"><img alt src="Images/TheLakeDistrict.jpg" class="ImgRound"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="Images/FlowerTable.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery" data-title="Dressing Table"><img alt src="Images/FlowerTable.jpg" class="ImgRound"></a>
            </div>
</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My Tables:

[image: Image Table]

I think my PHP query would look something like this:

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT * FROM `tblImage` WHERE `fldMemberID` = 1";

$result = $conn -> query($query);

while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
?>

    <img src="<?php echo $row['fldFilePath'];  ?>"> <br>

<?php
}
$conn -> close();
?>
```

UPDATE: After running the code, the following errors I get this appear where the gallery should be:
[image]

Comment: What's your question? Did you try to run your code?

Comment: So the question is that I need the gallery to be filled with images that are saved within the database table called Images as appose to just links to an image and I can't find the right php code to do this

Comment: _"I guess the html code of the gallery should fall within the php while loop ?"_ and _"I think my PHP query would look something like this"_. - Haven't you even written and/or tried your code before posting? We're not human compilers that checks your code for you before you run it. We're here if you run into some _specific issue_ with your _existing_ code after you've run it.

Comment: I mean, the code you posted looks legit and should solve your problem. What's your question, exactly?

Comment: Thank you for that input @MagnusEriksson yes I had ran the code and it's not quite right, so I came on here just looking for some advice, thanks anyway

Comment: Looks like `$conn -> query($query);` is returning `null`. Are you sure the connection to the db is ok? Check `$conn->connect_error`.

Comment: Hey @JohnnyMopp thank you for your reply, forgive me but can I paste that in before the query, or after?

Comment: Did you actually make a connection to a database? i.e. where is the `$conn = new mysqli(.....);` call in your code

Comment: at the top of the page there is `<?php
    require 'header.php';
?>` and in the header states `require "includes/dbh.inc.php";` I have other queries on the page which run fine

Comment: `fetch_assoc() on NULL` tend to normally mean the query failed as it means that `$result` is NULL and not a mysqli::result object as it shoudl be after a select query

Comment: @RiggsFolly ah right, I see, ok. I'll have to think of another way around getting the photos from the table to appear in the gallery, but thank you all for all your help :)

Comment: Try adding some error reporting Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`
 to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you, I pasted that code before the query ran and for some reason I just get the same errors. Very frustrating! It's obviously something I've screwed up somewhere

Comment: Is it possible that you ran a `$conn -> close();` somewhere before this code ran? In reality I never do that, because PHP will do that for me when the script terminates.

Comment: @RiggsFolly oh my lord, yes after another php query that I ran further up the page I had that exact line, now I've  deleted it, it runs. You don't know how much you've helped me and been so kind (with not writing some sad sarcastic comment like others). have a lovely evening!! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was given by another user @RiggsFolly in the comments, further up in the code I had used a `$conn -> close();` by deleting this the code ran fine.